# Mysql query where column has several values

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've been trying to find a way to get a value from a column using mysql query.

The column (lets talk about colors) has several foreign keys (with no foreign constraint). So imagine a shirt can have blue and black, the column "color" will have "1,10" being 1-Blue and 10-Black, both foreign keys.

I want to create query to search if the color blue is being used so I can prevent deleting that color from his original table. Although it sounds easy, I can't use:

```
SELECT * FROM shirt WHERE color LIKE '%$id%'
```

The problem if it there's no blue color being used it will still find the black (10) and give a true value to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM shirt WHERE FIND_IN_SET($id, color) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it did work. I was unware of that precious function

Answer (score 1):

Well.. if I understand your question right. You are storing the values as a comma seperated string. You want to search whether any t-shirt holds that color.

```
$colorToSearchFor = '1'; //blue.. sepearte it by comma to check for several colors at the same time e.g '1,10'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shirt WHERE color IN(colorToSearchFor)";

//count the results, if it's more than one then a t-shirt has the specifik color assigned.
```

It would be recommendable to have two different tables. One for the t-shirts and one for the colors.

Comment: They are in different tables and i wan't to avoid deleting colors being used. This works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Oh, and one table for what colors each t-shirt holds :) that would be a better structure.